# Why does the code only works when it's not in a function in Python?

Tags: python, function, global-variables

I think its a global or local error but I dont get it.

```
def who_wins_when_player_3(player):
    if player == 3:
        amount_triangles = np.count_nonzero(board == 3)
        if amount_triangles == 3 or 5 or 7:
            player = 2
        else:
            player = 1
```

here it doesn't work:

```
    # vertical win check
    for col in range(BOARD_COLS):
        if board[0][col] == player and board[1][col] == player and board[2][col] == player or board[3][col] == player and board[1][col] == player and board[2][col] == player:
            who_wins_when_player_3()
            print(f"Player {player} wins")
            return True
```

here it works:

```
    # vertical win check
    for col in range(BOARD_COLS):
        if board[0][col] == player and board[1][col] == player and board[2][col] == player or board[3][col] == player and board[1][col] == player and board[2][col] == player:
            if player == 3:
                amount_triangles = np.count_nonzero(board == 3)
                if amount_triangles == 3 or 5 or 7:
                    player = 2
                else:
                    player = 1
            print(f"Player {player} wins")
            return True
```

where is the error?

Best regards

Comment: Function have to return something.

Comment: still doesnt work :(

Comment: `if amount_triangles == 3 or 5 or 7` That is the wrong way to check for multiple values.  See this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/15112125/494134

Comment: `player` is a local variable in `who_wins_when_player_3`. Altering it inside the function has no effect on any similarly named variable outside the function.

Comment: I don't see how the second code block even runs.  You're calling `who_wins_when_player_3()` which is an error because that function requires an argument, and you are calling it without any arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assigning a value inside the function doesn't do anything unless you `return` the value.  Try this version of the function where the winning value of `player` is returned:

```
def who_wins_when_player_3(player):
    if player == 3:
        amount_triangles = np.count_nonzero(board == 3)
        if amount_triangles == 3 or 5 or 7:
            return 2
        else:
            return 1
    return player  # if we don't do this, the function will return None if player != 3
```

and then have the caller assign it to `player` within its own scope:

```
    # vertical win check
    for col in range(BOARD_COLS):
        if board[0][col] == player and board[1][col] == player and board[2][col] == player or board[3][col] == player and board[1][col] == player and board[2][col] == player:
            player = who_wins_when_player_3(player)  # pass player in and reassign it
            print(f"Player {player} wins")
            return True
```

There may be other problems with this code, but this hopefully at least clarifies how returning a value from a function works.